# How to change the name of a type key selected using Pick?

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
type Item = {
  title: string
}
```

and I want to `Pick` the `title` property as use it in another type definition:

```
type NewItem = Pick<Item, 'title'>
```

However, in `NewType` I want `title` to be named `newTitle`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even use `Pick` anymore:

```
type Item = {
  title: string
};

type NewItem = {
    newTitle: Item["title"];
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvGXRw)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) type utility to rename all of the picked properties, for example:

```ts
type PickAndRename<T, PropMap extends Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>> = {
  [
    K in keyof PropMap as K extends keyof T
      ? PropMap[K] extends string
        ? PropMap[K]
        : never
      : never
  ]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
};
```

which, when used with the details in your question:

```ts
type Item = {
  title: string;
};

type NewItem = PickAndRename<Item, { title: 'newTitle' }>;
```

results in a type that looks like this:

```ts
type NewItem = {
  newTitle: string;
};
```

---

An advantage of using a type utility is that you now have the flexibility to pick more than one property (just like with [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)) and rename it... all while using exactly the same syntax. For example:

```ts
type PersonDetails = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  nameLast: string;
};

type NewPersonDetails = PickAndRename<PersonDetails, {
  name: 'firstName';
  nameLast: 'lastName';
}>;

/* Looks like:

type NewPersonDetails = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

*/
```

It can also ignore when you pick invalid properties:

```ts
type NewPersonDetails2 = PickAndRename<PersonDetails, {
  name: 'firstName';
  age: 'personAge';
  somePropNotPresent: 'someNewName';
}>;

/* Looks like:

type NewPersonDetails2 = {
  firstName: string;
  personAge: number;
};

*/
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYEEB2ATAShNBDAWwgB4AVAGlgCcB7MAWTzCggA9hcMBnWPK4OHgA2xHAhpUMxJBBA0AZlApQuwKnDQBzAHy6oAXigBvAFBQoAbTPmoAaSgaoMuYpi0GTKHh722HTDzOCkrWNlAA-NR0jGAWtgC6LOycPKrqWqFhEVEesQmZYQBcUGgQAG4QVAVQxaUVVebxxb7JAU6ywaTZpHGJteWVANwmAL7DJgD0E1AAqlwQhSYmoJBQAJIcBAbG1gLAQgsqahqaw2NLK9AAchAA7hsQW4bwyOjYuIQkDwSURlB7B2KAHJSrdSHB9hAgVARtpxpdYJUuDQ0AARCDAPBwIQ8Qymcx4TSHNAAVwIACMhtZ8ERimkTsNzDSIAAZbzAOnHLRneHga53GBIlHozHY3GwRCoTA4ZnEQVUZFojFYnG-amfYHyOAK4BXT5AxklT5s1TAoTsvVEA2jOFLZZ8qA3W7yxUilVcABM2xeUvespdwuVYrVTI1UCBWp1lqhhsJhyBkAVKJQROt5mRRDcdCuNGAbgg8zQHPDGYgTuj1thwyAA)

Answer (score 1):

@caTS has the better answer in this simple case. But I'm going to assume this example is contrived, and your real types are more complex.

---

Typically if you want to change a single prop drastically you are looking at more of a type operation like:

```
Omit<T, K> & { [newKey in K]: NewTypeHere }
```

Using that strategy you can make a type that renames a property like so:

```
type RenameProp<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends string> =
    Omit<T, K1> & { [newKey in K2]: T[K1] }
```

Which you would use like so:

```
type Item = {
  title: string
  content: string
}

type NewItem = RenameProp<Item, 'title', 'newTitle'>
const newItem: NewItem = { newTitle: 'testing', content: 'abc123' } // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShB2BDAthACgJwPZgDwBUAaKAaQEYoIAPYBAEwGcoBrCELAMyiNICZKa9Jg2AYAlvADmAPigBeAFBRlUAPLIxwAsXKyAZFADeUANrwIAdxJsoEvgF0AXNxPl7UAL4KFoSFACStMjyRkpQwJoANhDOIuJSYQDGWPC0qbGiEpIKXj7g0AByloEQwXKwCCjo2HglyMQA5BHA0Q2N5hb4URAN0grJ8CJQHXXORRZ1IcYdXS0xUE0QIlltUANpwM4NiABGiWS8AMwNnlAA9GdQHBIQCkA)

Comment: `Record<K2, T[K1]>` would also work in place of the mapped type (but I suppose it takes a little more to understand at first).

Comment: Mapped type vs `Record` seems to mostly be preference, far as I can tell.

Comment: Well Records can't express the values as a result of their keys - for example, `{ [K in Union]: K }` is not possible to represent with a Record.

Comment: Sure, but I meant in the simple cases. Either way, we digress from the question :)